# Database design -relation among entities

Tags: database

I have:

- request has ID as PK and other attributes.
- customer database where ID is PK and other attributes
- visitor entity and the phone number can be a PK.

---

- customer and visitor can make request.
- I need to record whom make the request
- The customer ID has different format than the phone number.
- I add a FK called requestID inside the visitor table and make it the PK so the visitor is identified by his request.
- But the problem is how to connect the customer to its request?
- My suggested solutions:
- Add FK inside the customer table ---> I can not change the database
- creating a new table and copy customer info and adding the new column --> will contains redundancy.
- Create a new table contains a requestID and customerID ---> but the relation is not many-to-many to make it in separate table(customer can make many request and request is made by exactly one customer) and I don't no if that is a god practices.
- Add FK inside request table identified whom make the request ---> the problem is the domain is not the same.

Kindly see the image for my entities and tell me what is the best way to connect the customer?
[image]

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

If a Customer can make many Requests, and Request can belong to only one Customer, then you need a foreign key in Request to reference its Customer.

If a Customer can be associated with many Visitors, then Visitor should have that foreign key to Customer.  You'd think of Visitor as a JOIN table to make a Customer with its Requests.

Answer (score 0):

In my view you should add polymorphic association between.

Request table, Visitor table and Request table, Customer table

For that you can add two column in request table.

1. requester_id
2. requester_type

requester_id will hold id of parent table (Customer / Visitor)

requester_type will hold model/table of parent table (Customer / Visitor)

You should have this relationship in your tables.

`visitor can have many requests` and
`customer can have many request`